# MultiSelectList constructor

Tags: model-view-controller

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470803.aspx, the `MultiSelectList(IEnumerable, IEnumerable)` constructor takes in two parameters: `items` and `selectedValues`.

The documentation is not completely explicit so I just want to clarify two points:

1. How exactly does `selectedValues` work? Does this constructor merely iterate through the collection and set `.Selected = True` for each element?
2. Must `selectedValues` be a subset of `items`? How is this defined, precisely (i.e. as long as their ToString values match)?

Specifically, I am playing with [a jQuery multiselect plugin](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) and am trying to do essentially what is being done in the demo of that plugin (i.e. the "selected" list is already populated by certain elements upon initialization).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<%=Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.tempCategories, (MultiSelectList)(ViewData["Categories"]), new {@size = "5" })%>
```

Controller code:

```
 List<Categories> categoriesList = categories.Select();
 ViewData["Categories"] = GenCategoryMultiList(categoriesList);


private System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList GenCategoryMultiList(List<TemplateCategories> entity)
    {
        entity = entity.OrderBy(e => e.CategoryName).ToList();
        System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList selectList = new System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList(entity, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        return selectList;
    }
```

I am using this with JQuery Multiselect. Working code...